# error=24, Too many open files. Deleted files are still open

Tags: java, linux, pid

I have a method that fetch folder file . I only read the filename of the file. At the end of my program I delete the file. The problem is there's a time that "Too many open files" error appear.
I found out that the deleted files are still open.
[image]

Here are my codes:

**Getting file**

```
private File getFile(String fileName,String filetype) {
            File dir = new File("./");
            File[] foundFiles = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) { 
                    return name.startsWith(fileName) && name.endsWith(filetype);
                }
            }); 
            if(foundFiles.length!=0) {
                return foundFiles[0];
            }
}
...
File tempFile = this.getFile("versions.sh_",".pid");
String fileName = tempFile.getName();
int startNo = fileName.indexOf("_") + 1;
int endNo = startNo + 5;
pid = fileName.substring(startNo, endNo);
//other logic
```

**Deleting File**

```
if (pidFile != null) {
                logger.info("Deleting pidFile file = " + pidFile.toString());
                Files.deleteIfExists(pidFile.toPath());
}
```

Know I want to get rid of the code that open the file but I dont know which part of my code.
Btw this program runs on linux.

----- **update**
The .pid file is created by script

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT_PID=`echo $$`

ME=`basename "$0"`

SCRIPT_DIR=$(pwd)
RESULT_TXT=${SCRIPT_DIR}/${ME}_result.txt
PID_FILE=${SCRIPT_DIR}/${ME}_${SCRIPT_PID}.pid

echo $$ > $PID_FILE
```

Comment: You still have the file open somewhere either via a `FileInputStream`, `FileOutputStream` or some channel or something. Close that. "Deleting" a file on unix only unlinks its name. If a file has no names left **and** isn't opened by any process **then** it will actually be removed entirely.

Comment: I already check and I dont have FileInputStream, FileOutputStream or other stream in my code. Weird right?

Comment: In order for a file to be open, something must be opening it.  Deleting a file does not open it.  Ergo, it is happening in code that you haven't shown us.  If our hints don't help, you need to write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will allow us to figure out what you are actually doing, and what is actually going wrong.

Comment: @acer23: then shows us what you *do* with the `File` object returned here. *Something* must be opening it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I only used the file to get the file name.

Comment: I updated my post. The PID file was created by a script. Do you think the script is the one who opens the file?

Comment: It does look like these files are opened by your code - somewhere. You could confirm this with `lsof`, see if that points to your own application or identifies another application in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code keeps the file/folder open in linux. So i used `DirectoryStream` and `try-resources` block to implement auto-closable to the used resources.

```
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> paths = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(base),
                    path -> path.getFileName().toString().startsWith(fileName) && path.toString().endsWith(filetype))) {

                paths.forEach(path -> pathList.add(path));

                if (pathList.size() > 0) {
                    file = pathList.get(0).toFile();
                }
            }
```